# String Slice Syntax on PySpark Column Object Behaves Like Substring?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

PySpark 3.1.2

I am using [`input_file_name()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name.html) to add a column with partition information to my DataFrame. More specifically, I'm parsing the return value (a [`Column object`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.html)) to extract a substring of the file path. Like so:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
df = spark.read.parquet(*path_list).withColumn("partition", input_file_name()[81:13])
```

The part of the file path I'm interested in is a yyyy_mm_dd_hh value. If the return type of `input_file_name()` were a string, I would extract it with standard Python string slice syntax: `returned_column[80:93]`. Experimentation revealed that I can extract this data via `input_file_name()[81:13]`, effectively the same as calling [`substring`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.substring.html) thus: `substring(returned_string, 81, 13)`.

So, there are two behaviors I found unexpected in this situation:

1. Indices start at 1 in PySpark (rather than the 0 used in most of Python)
2. PySpark (or at least the `input_file_name()` method) treats slice syntax as equivalent to the `substring(str, pos, len)` method, rather than the more conventional `[start:stop]`.

Perusing the source code of [`Column`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/column.html#:%7E:text=def%20__getitem__(self%2C%20k)%3A), it looks like this might be why the slice syntax works this way on Column objects:

```
def __getitem__(self, k):
    if isinstance(k, slice):
        if k.step is not None:
            raise ValueError("slice with step is not supported.")
        return self.substr(k.start, k.stop)
    else:
        return _bin_op("apply")(self, k)
```

I am an analyst rather than a developer, so I may be out of my depth here. Could someone more knowledgeable:

- Confirm whether I've correctly understood the index and slice syntax behavior in PySpark?
- Provide any background on why these design decisions were taken, despite being seemingly at odds with Python convention?

Thank you very much!

Comment: for the design decision it's better to ask in the spark-devel mailing list...